# Steenrod algebra at a prime power

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, steenrod-algebra

Let $n=p^k$ be a prime power.

When $k=1$, the algebra of stable operations in mod $p$ cohomology is the [Steenrod algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steenrod_algebra) $\mathcal{A}_p$. It has a nice description in terms of generators and relations. Its dual (as a Hopf algebra) is also well understood by work of Milnor.

What about when $k>1$? Has any work been done on trying to understand the algebra of stable operations in mod $n$ cohomology? For instance, is there a description of $\mathcal{A}_4$ in terms of generators and relations? What about the dual Hopf algebra?

Of course I am just asking about the cohomology ring $H^\ast (H\mathbb{Z}/n;\mathbb{Z}/n)$, where $H\mathbb{Z}/n$ denotes the mod $n$ Eilenberg--Mac Lane spectrum. So I fully expect the answer to be either one of "yes, this is well-known and classical" or "no, this is known to be a big mess".

Comment: This is not directly related, but it is not hard to compute the Steenrod algebra corresponding a finite field. I am guessing you are not interested in that though.

Comment: @Sean: I am perhaps not so interested in the answer for finite fields, but I would be interested to know why it is easier (presumably issues with the Kunneth Theorems and duality)?

Comment: If I remember correctly, this can be calculated because the mod-$p$ Steenrod algebra has a relatively simple structure when considered as a bimodule over the subalgebra generated by the Bockstein.  (I'm less sure at odd primes.)  For $p=2$: in degrees zero and one you get $\mathbb{Z}/2^k$, generated by the Bockstein; I believe that in higher degrees it's abstractly isomorphic to the Steenrod algebra as a module except that admissible monomials starting with $Sq^1$ start with the Bockstein $\beta$ and admissible monomials ending with $Sq^r$, $r$ odd, end with $\beta Sq^{r-1}$.  A lot of the mul

Comment: Err, a lot of the multiplications become zero.

Comment: @Tyler: This sounds promising. Was this a self-made calculation? If not, is there any hope that you could remember where you are remembering it from? Thanks.

Comment: @Mark: I do remember reading somewhere in one of Adams' texts - possibly the Berkeley lectures? - about looking at cohomology operations into or out of mod $2^n$ cohomology.  I might start looking there.  The method is to filter $H\mathbb{Z}/p^n$ by $H\mathbb{Z}/p^k$ and look at the two associated Bockstein sequences that you get.  Sorry for the indeterminacy in references.

Comment: @Tyler: Thanks for the tip. I've ordered Adams' Berkeley notes from our library, I'll let you know if I find anything!

Comment: @Mark: Did you figure out a satisfactory answer? I had a thought about one possible way to "reverse engineer" it.

Comment: @Sean: No. Shortly after asking this question I started working on other things. I did check out Adams' Berkeley notes, but couldn't find anything therein. Tyler's answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119604/computation-of-hz-4-hz-4 seems encouraging though.

Comment: I know that this is another question but as it is related I'm taking the liberty to ask it here: has anything been written about mod p^k Dyer Lashof operations ? I would especially be interested in mod 4 ones. Please tell me if this deserves a new thread.

Comment: @elidiot: I don't know anything about mod p^k Dyer-Lashof operations, but that's probably just my own ignorance. It seems worthy of an MO question for sure!